# How to populate old select option values?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select box in my form that looks like below :

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
  @if(count($category_list)>0)
       <option value="null">Pick a Category</option>
       @foreach($category_list as $cl)
           <option value="{{$cl->id}}">{{$cl->name}}</option>
       @endforeach
  @else
       <option>No categories found</option>
  @endif
</select>
```

My question is, how do I populate the select option with `old` selected option when the validation fails ? By populate I mean like `{{old('input')}}`..

I tried this way :

```
@if(old('category_id')
   <option value="{{old('category_id')}}">{{old name ???}}</option>
@endif
```

But it will only get the `category_id` value, not the category name. How to get the old category name as well ? that's all and thanks!

Comment: this will give you the value inside `value` attribute of option tag not text of Option tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
  @if(count($category_list)>0)
   <option value="null">Pick a Category</option>
   @foreach($category_list as $cl)
       <option value="{{$cl->id}}" @if(old('category_id') == $cl->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{$cl->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
 @else
   <option>No categories found</option>
@endif
```